# Java lottery using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create  a lottery game where you randomly generate six winning numbers simulating a lottery.   Ask the  user to enter six numbers and see if they win the lottery!

I have done a lot of it, but now im stuck. I am really new to java so forgive me. When it prompts to ask for another number it does it but it still displays it for the self-made lottery picks that display. Also, when displaying the numbers for the computer made lottery picks they are the same numbers over again that repeat and aren't 6 numbers. The counter doesn't work as well it maybe a little thing but i can't figure it out. Thank you

```
package arraysIntroduction;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class sizeQuestion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int [] user =new int [6];
    int i;
    //Fill user array 

        System.err.println("Welcome to Miwand's Lottery");
        System.out.println("Please enter your 6 desiered number to enter the lottery");
        System.out.println("Pick from 1 to 49");

    for (  i=0;i<user.length;i++) // gets numbers until it equals 6
    {
        System.out.println("Number:");

        user[i]= in.nextInt(); // Gets numbers from user

        while  (user[i] < 0 ) // if its a negative number tell user to enter again
        {
        System.err.println("Negative number, please enter again:");
        user[i]=in.nextInt();
        }

if (user[i] > 49) // if the number goes past 49 prompt again
{
    System.err.println("Please enter numbers from 1 - 49");
    }
}


    //print out the numbers generated
    for ( i=0;i < user.length; i++){
        System.out.print(+user[i]+ " ");    

    }

System.out.println(" ");

int[] lottery = new int[6];

int guesses;
int counter=0;
int j;
int x;
    {
for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() *49 +1); // Random number created here.
for ( x = 0; x < j; x++) {
    if (lottery[x] == randomNum) // Here, code checks if same random number    generated before.
    {
        randomNum = (int) (Math.random() *49 +1);// If random number is same, another number generated.
    }
    lottery[j] = randomNum;
}
}



//prints out computer generated numbers

for (i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++){
for (x = 0; x< j; x++){
 System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
if (user[i] == lottery[x] ){
    counter++;
    }
}
}
    }
if (counter < 2){

    System.out.println("Try again!");
}

if (counter == 3){

    System.out.println("3 numbers matched! You won $300!");
}

if (counter == 4){

    System.out.println("4 numbers matched! You won 500!");
}

if (counter == 5){

    System.out.println(" 5 numbers matched! You won $1000!");
}

else if (counter == 6){

    System.out.println("JACCKKKPOOOOTTTTTTT!!!!!! YOU WIN 1 MILLION DOLLARS!");
    }
}
        }
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: sorry what?Im new

Comment: I noticed, welcome to StackOverflow! You added the `javascript` tag to this question, but your question is about Java; they have nothing to do with one another. (I removed it :) )

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know the difference

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once**.

Comment: Further reading for OP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: sorry, the question was how do i fix it so the computer generated code that displays the code doesn't display the same numbers over again repeating 4 times for example if it generated 4 2 5 45 23 24, but instead it displays 0 0 0 0 0 0 49 49 49 49 49 49 46 46 46 46 46 46 13 13 13 13 13 13 36 36 36 36 36 36 29 29 29 29 29 29 Try again!

Comment: Move the print statement from the inner to the outer loop

Comment: like this? //prints out computer generated numbers

    for (i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++){
 for (x = 0; x< j; x++){
   
 if (user[i] == lottery[x] ){
  counter++;
            }
    }
}

System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
  }
 if (counter < 2){
  
  System.out.println("Try again!");
 }

 if (counter == 3){
  
  System.out.println("3 numbers matched! You won $300!");
 }

 if (counter == 4){

Comment: It says error when i moved it

Comment: What if `counter` equals 2? There doesn’t seem to be a case for that (maybe you intended `if (counter <= 2)` in the first case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw multiple problems in your program.

First, the printout problem can be solved by moving the print statement from inner loop to outer loop

```
for (i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
    for (x = 0; x < j; x++) {
        if (user[i] == lottery[x]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you are not assigning the first random number correctly and it is always using the default, which is 0

Solution:

```
 for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1); // Random number created here.
    for (x = 0; x < j; x++) {
        if (lottery[x] == randomNum) // Here, code checks if same random number    generated before.
        {
            randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);// If random number is same, another number generated.
        }
    }
    lottery[j] = randomNum;
}
```

Plus, you didn't check if counter is equal to 2

Solution:

```
if (counter <= 2) {
   System.out.println("Try again!");
}
```

And, the logic in "If random number is same, another number generated." may not be correct, since it may generate the same number again. You need a while loop to generate a new number until it is not equal to any of the generated numbers.

Another thing about coding style is that for any "for loops"

This :

```
int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Should be replaced by this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments, you should move the print statement from the inner loop to the outer loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {   // outer loop
    System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
    for (x = 0; x < j; x++) {            // inner loop
        if (user[i] == lottery[x]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```